# WooCommerce email IDs and order status change for email notifications

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am trying to add a function that will log any email that is sent through order status changes.

Is there a hook I can use that is triggered right before an order notification email is sent?

Comment: Use [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

All the available hooks responsible for triggering email notifications are located in [**`WC_Emails` `init_transactional_emails()`** method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Emails.html#65-102) and are action hooks:

- `woocommerce_low_stock`,
- `woocommerce_no_stock`,
- `woocommerce_product_on_backorder`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_cancelled`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_failed`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_processing`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_cancelled`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_failed`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_completed`,
- `woocommerce_order_fully_refunded`,
- `woocommerce_order_partially_refunded`,
- `woocommerce_new_customer_note`,
- `woocommerce_created_customer`.

> Each of those action hooks can **queue** or **send** transactional emails as you will see in the source code on [**line 95**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Emails.html#95) or on [**line 99**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Emails.html#99).

Last thing for the **new order notification**, which is a bit appart, you will use one of those:

- `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_notification`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_notification`,
- `woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_notification`,

as documented in [this `WC_Email_New_Order` code source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email_New_Order.html#37-43).

---

Or you can detect status changes using one of the 3 hooks located in [`status_transition()` `WC_Order` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#317-343):

- `woocommerce_order_status_changed`
- `woocommerce_order_status_{$status_transition[from]}_to_{$status_transition[to]}`
- `woocommerce_order_status_{$status_transition[to]}`

> The `status_transition()` is included in [`set_status()` `WC_Order` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#230-255) *(and so also* [`update_status()` *method*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#289-315) too which call `set_status()`*)*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not trying to detect status changes, I am trying to detect when orders statuses triggers email notifications to be sent so I can log them (as an order note or some other way).

Comment: Yes but if I change a completed order back to proccessing the new order email is not resent so this is why I am searching a hook that is depedent to the emails rather than the ones with order statuses. I guess that I could find all the possible senarios that an email is sent from every status transition but I was wondering if there is a better way than that.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Vpant Just added some additional info regarding "new Order"… So my first answer was good as all hooks used are made on this composite hooks: `woocommerce_order_status_{$status_transition[to]}` or `woocommerce_order_status_{$status_transition[from]}_to_{$status_transition[to]}`…